# How to create Event Trigger in Azure Data Factory when two files created in Azure Blob Container?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I need to create an event trigger in the Azure Data Factory, which will execute when two different files created in an Azure Blob Storage Container. The trigger should be executed once both files are created in the blob container.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible as is . But I am very confident that using a GetMetadata activity with foreach activity we can achieve this , with this workaround look for the file(s)( using the GetMetaData activity)  and once you have the condition met , copy a dummy file to a different container and point the event trigger to that new container .